# Русский язык в GUI приложении Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Пишу GUI приложение на Qt. Хочу установить title окна "Текстовый редактор", но отображаются "Крокозябры".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал добавить в файл main.cpp следующую строку.

```
  QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251"));
```

Выдало такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это строка вроде бы должна влиять только на консольные приложения (Если не прав, поправьте), поэтому возник вопрос: Как поменять кодировку в GUI-приложении Qt? Ну и как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Убедитесь что у ваших файлов с кодом везде кодировка utf-8 стоит, тогда не будет проблем и не понадобится вызывать QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale. Настройте еще в IDE чтобы кодировка всегда была utf-8, а не системная как обычно бывает. А еще можно сделать так: `QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("utf-8"));`, только опять же кодировка самих страниц должна быть такой же -- utf-8

Comment: А как добавить кодировку utf-8 в коде? Charset или что-нибудь подобное есть?

Comment: Открыть файл в редакторе и поменять кодировку. Например, в notepad++ это `Кодировки/Преобразовать в UTF-8`. Думаю, через редактор IDE тоже можно, но тут не подскажу

Comment: Для QtCreator: Смена кодировки для текущего файла: `Edit \ Select Encoding`. Смена кодировки по умолчанию (для новых файлов): `Tools \ Options \ Text Editor \ Behavior \ File encodings` .

Comment: Для Qt 4.8 выручает `trUtf8("Какой-то русский текст")`, однако, если не ошибаюсь, в Qt 5 не актуально, т.к. этот метод признан устаревшим.